# Compound Interest calculator has problems in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been experimenting with creating an investment calculator, and I want to print the annual totals as well as the annual compounded interest. It's doing the annual totals fine, but not the annual interest. My inputs are $10000.00 principle, at 5% interest over 5 years.

```
start_over = 'true'
while start_over == 'true':
    principle = int(input("Type the amount you are investing: "))
    rate = float(input("Type interest rate"))
    addition = int(input("Type annual Addition"))
    time = int(input("Enter number of years to invest"))
    real_rate = rate * 0.01
    i = 1

    print('total', principle * (1 + real_rate))

    while i < time:
        principle = (principle + addition) * (1 + real_rate)
        i = i + 1
        print('total', principle)

     for i in range(time):
        amount = i * (((1 + rate/100.0) ** time)) * principle
        ci = amount - principle
        i += 1
        print("interest = ",ci)

    redo_program = input('To restart type y or to quit type any key ')
    if redo_program == 'y':
        start_over = 'true'
    else:
        start_over = 'null'
```

Here are my outputs:

```
Type the amount you are investing: 10000
Type interest rate5
Type annual Addition0
Enter number of years to invest5
total 10500.0
total 10500.0
total 11025.0
total 11576.25
total 12155.0625
interest =  -12155.0625
interest =  3358.21965978516
interest =  18871.50181957032
interest =  34384.78397935548
interest =  49898.06613914064
To restart type y or to quit type any key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
# Calculate year's values based on inputs and the current value of the account
def calc(current, addition, rate, year):
    multiplier = 1 + rate/100 # The interest multiplier
    new_total = (current + addition) * multiplier # Calculate the total
    interest = round((new_total - current - addition), 2) # Interest to nearest penny/cent
    return new_total, interest


def main():
    # Inputs
    principle = int(input("Type the amount you are investing: "))
    rate = float(input("Type interest rate: "))
    addition = int(input("Type annual Addition: "))
    invst_time = int(input("Enter number of years to invest: "))
    # Sets current account value to principle
    current = principle
    # Prints values for each year of investment
    for i in range(invst_time):
        total, interest_gained = calc(current, addition, rate, i+1)
        print("At the end of Year: ", i+1)
        print("Total: ", total)
        print("Interest: ", interest_gained)
        print("------")
        current = total # Updates value of account
    # Restart Program check
    while 1:
        repeat_choice = input("Would you like to restart and check with different values? (Y/N)")
        if repeat_choice == "Y":
            main() 
        elif repeat_choice == "N":
            print("Thanks for using the calculator")
            break
        else:
            print("Enter Y or N!") # Error handler
            continue

main()
```

Comment: That works very well, I just changed "principle = int(input(....)" to "principle = float(input(...) so that you can put in cents if necessary... Thank you for your help!!